# RPi 3B not booting, only a stable red light

Tags: boot, led

As I said in the title, my RPi 3B just wont boot and has a stable red light.

I have tried the following:

- Re-flashing using balena etcher and raspberry pi OS flasher
- Using multiple different power supplies that are known good and enough for the RPi 3B.
- Using a different SD card
- Trying everything mentioned [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com//viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a new 3B? Has it ever worked? What size sd card? Is the sd card new? Have you got another Pi? Have you got an official Pi power supply?

Comment: There is absolutely no point in asking an "it doesn't work" question unless you post diagnostics and explain EXACTLY what YOU did. If you tried EVERYTHING what else do you think we could add.

Comment: The pi has been with me since 2017, but I left it in my closet for like 1.5 years and I have just now come back to use it. The PSUs I used are a 5v 2.4 amps one, which did work in the past on my rpi and still works on other devices, and a 5v 1 amp one which used to work on the same rpi and still works on other devices. Also I tried the SD card I flashed for the rpi 3  on the rpi 4 and it booted up with no issues

Comment: I don't know how to reply on this platform lol

Comment: `tried the SD card I flashed for the rpi 3 on the rpi 4 and it booted` possibly a dirty/damaged SD card slot, or a dead pi. Does it output anything to the screen? Do you recall ever enabling USB boot, that could allow you to check if the SD slot is the only thing malfunctioning?

Comment: Unfortunately I never enabled usb boot on ny rpi 3, also I bent the pins upwards so that it makes good content with the SD card but no luck

Comment: Normally when people ask vague questions I suggest the sticky link you listed. This has a detailed set of steps to diagnose the problem. I suggest you check these and post the results if you can't fix it.

Comment: Hello Milliways, I have tried everything in the sticky link, but no luck unfortunately. Here's the thing though, there's a chance i might have accidentally shorted 5v to 3v3 on the GPIO. If that's the case, is there a way of fixing it? (I can solder) Any help is appreciated